Error trying to calculate the NDVI of about 20 cities in the USA in GEE
I am new to GEE. I am trying to calculate the NDVI of about 20 cities in the USA. However, I keep getting this error:

Error: User memory limit exceeded. (Error code: 3)

I don't know how to solve it. How can I do this? There are still 20 GB on my Google Drive, which should be enough for a CSV file.
Here is my code:
/*
 * Remote Sensing for Environmental Health
 * Final Project(Urban Green Space Area 2014)
 * Time: May 10, 2024*/

// Step 1: Set up city boundaries

var roi = CityBoundaries;

// Step 2: Define a function to calculate NDVI

function calculateNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI'); // Use 'SR_B4' for Near Infrared
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

// Step 3: Apply NDVI calculation to Landsat images

var Landsat2008 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(roi);
var Landsat_withNDVI = Landsat2008.map(calculateNDVI);

// Step 4: Define a threshold for NDVI to identify green areas

var NDVI_threshold = 0.2;

// Step 5: Mask pixels below the NDVI threshold to extract green areas

var greenAreas = Landsat_withNDVI.map(function(image) {
  var greenMask = image.select('NDVI').gte(NDVI_threshold);
  return image.updateMask(greenMask);
});

// Step 6: Calculate the area of green space

var greenSpaceArea = greenAreas.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).multiply(30 * 30).divide(10000); // Convert square meters to hectares
print(greenSpaceArea)

// Step 7: Overlay city boundaries with green space area and calculate sum within each city

var greenSpaceInCities = greenSpaceArea.reduceRegions({
  collection: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 30,
});

// Step 8: Export the result as a CSV file

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: greenSpaceInCities,
  description: 'urban_green_space_by_city_1',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});


 * Remote Sensing for Environmental Health
 * Final Project(Urban Green Space Area 2014)
 * Time: May 10, 2024

// Step 1: Set up city boundaries

var roi = CityBoundaries;

// Step 2: Define a function to calculate NDVI

function calculateNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI'); // Use 'SR_B4' for Near Infrared
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

// Step 3: Apply NDVI calculation to Landsat images

var Landsat2008 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(roi);
var Landsat_withNDVI = Landsat2008.map(calculateNDVI);

// Step 4: Define a threshold for NDVI to identify green areas

var NDVI_threshold = 0.2;

// Step 5: Mask pixels below the NDVI threshold to extract green areas

var greenAreas = Landsat_withNDVI.map(function(image) {
  var greenMask = image.select('NDVI').gte(NDVI_threshold);
  return image.updateMask(greenMask);
});

// Step 6: Calculate the area of green space

var greenSpaceArea = greenAreas.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).multiply(30 * 30).divide(10000); // Convert square meters to hectares
print(greenSpaceArea)

// Step 7: Overlay city boundaries with green space area and calculate sum within each city

var greenSpaceInCities = greenSpaceArea.reduceRegions({
  collection: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 30,
});

// Step 8: Export the result as a CSV file

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: greenSpaceInCities,
  description: 'urban_green_space_by_city_1',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});


Claiming you still have space on a cloud device while getting memory errors is a bit like the person saying "I can't be overdrawn -- My checkbook still has checks in it!" Memory and disk are different kinds of resources, each of which can be exhausted independently of the other.

Your code is incomplete, but at a guess, your ROI is very complex.
Don't filter with complex geometries, it's unnecessary and can take a lot of memory.  Use the .bounds() or just draw a box.
